# Preserving line breaks in an html form

Tags: php, html

I have a text area in a form `($bio)` where users can save text to a MySQL database.
I'm trying to preserve any line breaks a user might make in the text.

The text displays on another page how I want it (done like this):

```
<?php echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($bio));?>
```

But in the form page the html code that makes the line breaks is displayed (like this)

```
There is a line break<br />
here<br />
<br />
```

How can I hide this html code?

The form

```
<textarea name="bio" id="bio" placeholder="<?php echo  nl2br(htmlspecialchars($bio));?>"><?php echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($bio));?></textarea>
```

Thanks.

Comment: from PHP doc [comments](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.nl2br.php) and you can do smomething like `function back2nl($string) {  return preg_replace('#<br\s*/?-->#i', "\n", $string); }` (there are many of those)

Comment: I see. I can't quite figure out where I shoiuld use preg_replace in:  `<textarea name="bio" id="bio" placeholder="<?php echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($bio));?>"><?php echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($bio));?></textarea>`

Comment: I usually would assign the text value to a $var then perform the function, then echo it in the textarea

Comment: let me know if you succeeded

Comment: Yes, that worked. Many thanks.

Comment: answer posted, if you mind accepting it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[from PHP doc comments](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.nl2br.php) you can do smomething like

```
function back2nl($string) {
return preg_replace('#<br\s*/?-->#i', "\n", $string); }
```

(there are many of those)

I usually would assign the text value to a $var then perform the function, then echo it in the textarea